# how to put a masked textbox inside a datagridview

Tags: c#, .net

i need to put a maskedtextbox against each row in a particular column in the datagridview.can anyone please tell me how is it possible

Answer (score 1):

You create custom dataGridView column where place any control you want
[Here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/hosting-custom-control-datagridview-t2195638.html) is example